# Why isn't any data being sent when the form is submitted?

Tags: python, database, flask

This is my first project using backend code (python) and also using Flask as well. I have created a form using Flasks WTForms along with a db.model for it and a python @app.route for the data to be passed to a database which has been created and I can view it on SQLite Studio. However when pressing on submit, now data is being sent even though I am getting the HTTP 200 code in the terminal. The page should get redirected to the users account page once confirmed but it doesn't and stays on the booking page instead, which means that something is wrong but I don't know what.

Have I missed anything out?

My form

```html
<div class="form-wrapper">
    <div class="form-container">
        <form class="form-content" action="/bookings" method="POST">
            <input type="hidden" name="user_id" value="{{ current_user.id }}">
            <div class="fm-title">
                <h1>Appointment Request Form</h1>
                <h6>For all requests, please fill out the form below</h6>
                <hr>
            </div>
            <div class="fm-input">
                <div class="days">
                    <h5><strong>What day is best for you?</strong></h5>
                    {% if form.day.errors %}
                    {{ form.day(class="form-control form-control-md is-invalid required") }}
                    <div class="invalid-feedback">
                        {% for error in form.day.errors %}
                            <span>{{  error }}</span>
                        {% endfor %}
                    </div>
                {% else %}
                    {{ form.day(class="form-control form-control-md required") }}
                {% endif %}
                </div>
                <hr>
                <div class="time-frame">
                    <h5><strong>What time frame works best for you?</strong></h5>
                    {% if form.timeFrame.errors %}
                    {{ form.timeFrame(class="form-control form-control-md is-invalid required") }}
                    <div class="invalid-feedback">
                        {% for error in form.timeFrame.errors %}
                            <span>{{  error }}</span>
                        {% endfor %}
                    </div>
                {% else %}
                    {{ form.timeFrame(class="form-control form-control-md required") }}
                {% endif %}  
                </div>
                <hr>
                <div class="time">
                    <h5><strong>Do you have a preferable time?</strong></h5>
                    {% if form.time.errors %}
                    {{ form.time(class="form-control form-control-md is-invalid required") }}
                    <div class="invalid-feedback">
                        {% for error in form.time.errors %}
                            <span>{{  error }}</span>
                        {% endfor %}
                    </div>
                {% else %}
                    {{ form.time(class="form-control form-control-md required") }}
                {% endif %}           
                </div>
                <hr>
                <div class="trt-chk">
                    <h5><strong>Treatment choice</strong></h5>
                    <div class="grid">
                        <div class="g1">
                    <h6>Massage</h6>
                    {% if form.massage.errors %}
                    {{ form.massage(class="form-control form-control-md is-invalid required") }}
                    <div class="invalid-feedback">
                        {% for error in form.massage.errors %}
                            <span>{{  error }}</span>
                        {% endfor %}
                    </div>
                {% else %}
                    {{ form.massage(class="form-control form-control-md required") }}
                {% endif %}                  
                    <h6>Facials</h6>
                    {% if form.facials.errors %}
                    {{ form.facials(class="form-control form-control-md is-invalid required") }}
                    <div class="invalid-feedback">
                        {% for error in form.facials.errors %}
                            <span>{{  error }}</span>
                        {% endfor %}
                    </div>
                {% else %}
                    {{ form.facials(class="form-control form-control-md required") }}
                {% endif %}            
                        </div>
                        <div class="g2">
                    <h6>Hand & Foot</h6>
                    {% if form.handFoot.errors %}
                    {{ form.handFoot(class="form-control form-control-md is-invalid required") }}
                    <div class="invalid-feedback">
                        {% for error in form.handFoot.errors %}
                            <span>{{  error }}</span>
                        {% endfor %}
                    </div>
                {% else %}
                    {{ form.handFoot(class="form-control form-control-md required") }}
                {% endif %}              
                    <h6>Waxing</h6>
                    {% if form.waxing.errors %}
                    {{ form.waxing(class="form-control form-control-md is-invalid required") }}
                    <div class="invalid-feedback">
                        {% for error in form.waxing.errors %}
                            <span>{{  error }}</span>
                        {% endfor %}
                    </div>
                {% else %}
                    {{ form.waxing(class="form-control form-control-md required") }}
                {% endif %}               
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <hr>
                <div class="tc">
                    {% if form.terms.errors %}
                    {{ form.terms(class="form-control form-control-md is-invalid required") }}
                    <div class="invalid-feedback">
                        {% for error in form.terms.errors %}
                            <span>{{  error }}</span>
                        {% endfor %}
                    </div>
                {% else %}
                    {{ form.terms(class="required") }}
                {% endif %}
                {{ form.terms.label }}    
                </div>
                <hr>
                {{ form.submit(class="btn btn-dark") }}
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

My route

```py
@app.route('/bookings', methods=['GET','POST'])
@login_required
def bookings():
    form = BookingForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():         
        bookings = Booking(
            day = form.day.data, 
            timeFrame = form.timeFrame.data, 
            time = form.time.data, 
            massage = form.massage.data,
            facials = form.facials.data, 
            handFoot = form.handFoot.data, 
            waxing = form.waxing.data,
            terms = form.terms.data)  
        db.session.add(bookings)   
        db.session.commit()
        flash('Your treatment has been created successfully!')
        return render_template("account.html", form=form)
    else:
        return render_template("bookings.html", form=form)
```

my model

```py
class Booking(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    day = db.Column(db.String(50), nullable=False)
    timeFrame = db.Column(db.String(50), nullable=False, unique=True)
    time = db.Column(db.String(10), nullable=False, unique=True)
    massage = db.Column(db.String(50))
    facials = db.Column(db.String(50))
    handFoot = db.Column(db.String(50))
    waxing = db.Column(db.String(50))
    terms = db.Column(db.Boolean, nullable=False)
    user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.id'), nullable=False)

# Create A repr method (what gets printed out)

    def __repr__(self):
        return f"Booking('{self.day}', '{self.timeFrame}', '{self.time}', '{self.massage}', '{self.facials}', '{self.handFoot}', '{self.waxing}')"
    
    def __init__(self, day, timeFrame, time, massage, facials, handFoot, waxing, terms, user_id):
        self.day = day
        self.timeFrame = timeFrame
        self.time = time
        self.massage = massage
        self.facials = facials
        self.handFoot = handFoot
        self.waxing = waxing
        self.terms = terms
        self.user_id = user_id
```

```py
class BookingForm(FlaskForm):
        day = SelectField(
        choices=[
                ('','Please Choose a Day'),
                ('Mon','Monday'),
                ('Tues','Tuesday'),
                ('Wed','Wednesday'),
                ('Thurs','Thursday'),
                ('Fri','Friday'),
                ('Sat','Saturday'),
                ('Sun','Sunday')
                ])

        timeFrame = SelectField(      
        choices=[
                ('','Please Choose a Time Slot'),
                ('Morn','Morning(8am-12pm)'),
                ('After','Afternoon(12pm-5pm)'),
                ('Eve','Evening(5pm-10pm)')
                ])

        time = StringField(validators=[DataRequired(), Length(max=5)])

        massage = SelectField(u'Massage',
                        choices=[
                                ('','None'),
                                ('Body Radiance','Body Radiance'),
                                ('Deep Tissue','Deep Tissue'),
                                ('Sports Massage','Sports Massage')])

        facials = SelectField(u'Facials',
                          choices=[
                                ('','None'),
                                ('Dermaplane Facial','Dermaplane Facial'),
                                ('Microneedling Facial','Microneedling Facial'),
                                ('Biotec Facial','Biotec Facial')])

        handFoot = SelectField(u'Hand & Foot',
                          choices=[
                                ('','None'),
                                ('Manicure','Manicure'),
                                ('Pedicure','Pedicure'),
                                ('Ultimate Foot Transformation','Ultimate Foot Transformation')])

        waxing = SelectField(u'Waxing',
                          choices=[
                                ('','None'),
                                ('Bikini Wax','Bikini Wax'),
                                ('Full Leg Wax','Full Leg Wax'),
                                ('Mens Ultimate Ritual','Mens Ultimate Ritual')])
        terms = BooleanField('By clicking, you are accepting our Terms and Conditions', validators=[DataRequired()])

        submit = SubmitField('Submit')
```

When I create a user with my registration form that data is sent and can be viewed but for some reason my booking form can't.

I have looked everywhere for ideas but I guess at my level (which is a total novice) I could be looking at the answer and not even realize.

Comment: Have you looked in your browser's developer tools (in Chrome, you would look in the "Network" tab) to see if anything is being sent?

Comment: Also, I went back through my old Flask notes. I always used `action=""`, and sometimes added `enctype="multipart/form-data"` in the `<form>`. I feel like those shouldn't matter, but you could give it a try.

Comment: Last comment -- you haven't shared your code for `BookingForm`. There could be a problem with the class.

Comment: Sorry D.Hammaker I have only just seen this. Yes I have looked into the developer tools and it does say it has been sent...to my reckoning anyways. Just tried taking way the action value and the enctype but nothing happened again. I press submit and it stays on the booking page which says to me that the data isnt being sent due to the IF statement in my routing. I didnt add my code for the form as chatgpt said it was ok but I will try and edit my origional post and add it in to there.

Comment: The "IF statement"? If you are getting an error message, please share your traceback and we can see if that has a clue

Comment: Sorry, I meant the else part of the IF statement in my @app.route. If the data has been submitted then it should redirect to my users account page as stated but it doesn't. The pages refreshes back onto the bookings.html page, but I get a HTTP of 200 in the terminal (which is good I think). So im not sure what is going on

Comment: I think you'll have to troubleshoot each part of your request. My method may be less sophisticated than others', but I'd be using plain old `print` statements to figure out what's happening. Use `from flask import request` and start inserting `print("METHOD:", request.method)` and `print("FORM", request.form)` inside and outside your `if` statement. Double-check `account.html` to make sure it's not identical to `bookings.html` for some reason. That's where I'd start. I hope that helps.

Comment: I'd also give the docs another look and see if you want to try something different in your code. The "submit" button is different, for example. https://flask-wtf.readthedocs.io/en/1.1.x/quickstart/#creating-forms

Comment: Ok, I have used the Print inside and out the IF statement. Using the request.method I got nothing in the terminal. The only thing I got was the "POST /bookings HTTP/1.1" 200 - that I keep getting anyways. 
Now If I place the request.form outside the IF statement, so before "if request.method == POST, I get a print out of what I selected inside the form. However if I place it inside my IF statement I get nothing showing up at all. What does this mean? does this mean that my form isnt posting at all or being validated?